# Java Runtime Exception: USB to RS232 serial comm using jssc maven package

Tags: java, maven, javafx, serial-port, usb

I developed a desktop application using JavaFX and Maven dependency manager. I used Java 8 and JSSC package to communicate with a serial port using USB. That time it was working as I expected. But now when I try to run the project, it's showing me the following exception and shutdown the app.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=9452, tid=0x0000000000002384
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_332-b08) (build 1.8.0_332-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.332-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Sincos\Desktop\HomeOffice\Java\FDH-Relay\hs_err_pid9452.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I start the process, the following function is triggered.

```
public void open() throws SerialPortException {
    port = new SerialPort(comPort);
    port.openPort();//Open serial port
    port.setParams(Integer.parseInt(baudRate), Integer.parseInt(dataSize), Integer.parseInt(stopBit), Integer.parseInt(parity));
    port.addEventListener(new SerialPortEventListener() {
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
            try {
                int length = 0;
                buffer= port.readString();

                if (buffer != null){
                    length = buffer.length();
                }

                for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
                    queue.add((int)buffer.charAt(i));
                }
            } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I set up the port, baudRate, dataSize, stopBit, and parity.

Here is the maven dependency that I used in the project.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
    <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the other variable and constructor where I initialize the data.

```
String comPort;
public static Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
SerialPort port;
java.lang.String buffer;
String baudRate, dataSize, stopBit, parity;
public ExternalSerialConnection(String comport, String baudRate, String dataSize, String stopBit, String parity) {
    this.comPort=comport;
    this.baudRate=baudRate;
    this.stopBit=stopBit;
    this.dataSize=dataSize;
    this.parity=parity;
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you look into C:\Users\Sincos\Desktop\HomeOffice\Java\FDH-Relay\hs_err_pid9452.log as suggested?

Comment: You also might want to have a look at https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm instead which seems to be more popular (and works for me).

Comment: I received similar behavior when "disappearing / interrupting" the usb to rs interface. in other words, a purely hardware problem that leads to a direct crash of the platform. Another case of a similar bug I had when using java 9+ (certainly over 8) and rxtx libraries (which work great under linux).